# 6 graffiti artists paint 4 walls in 2 hours. How long does it take 4 graffiti artists to paint 8 walls?

Tags: word-problem

6 graffiti artists paint 4 walls in 2 hours. How long does it take 4 graffiti artists to paint 8 walls?

$$\frac{6}{4} \times x=2$$
$$x=\frac{2}{\frac{6}{4} } =\frac{8}{6} =\frac{4}{3}$$

Is that the hourly rate for each individual grafitti painter?

> How long does it take 4 graffiti artists to paint 8 walls?

$$\frac{4}{8} x=1,x=\frac{4}{3} \Rightarrow \frac{4}{8} \left( \frac{4}{3} \right)  \times t=1\Rightarrow \frac{16}{24} t=1\Rightarrow 16t=24\Rightarrow t=\frac{24}{16} =\frac{3}{2}$$

Answer: $$\boxed{3/2 \text{h}}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Your answer is $\frac 32$ of an hour?  But that would mean that $4$ artists paint much faster than $6$.  Or am I misreading?

Comment: @lulu The answer is 3/2 hours. I.e. 1.5hours.

Comment: Right...so you are claiming that the four artists are *much* faster than the six artists.  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Lulu 6 graffiti artists paint 4 walls in 2 hours. This means that they'd paint 2 walls in 1 hour, right? So the hourly rate for 6 graffiti artists are 2 walls. If we assume their work rate is constant. This means that it takes them 1/2 hours to finish painting 1 wall. And subsequently, if we assume that each painter work at the same rate as the others, then that'd mean each are doing their part in 5 minutes in that half hour. 

Is there a way to think about this in terms of a formula?

Comment: Say each artist does one unit of work per hour. $6$ graffiti artists working for $2$ hours do 12 units of work and four walls. Each wall is 3 units. The task for the $4$ artists is therefore ... $n$ units, and this will take $m$ hours. I find that using a "person hour" as a unit in this kind of problem tends to simplify it and avoid confusion. As here it enables a clear logical path.

Comment: Since $6$ artists do $4$ walls in $2$ hours, they would do $8$ walls in $4$ hours.  Therefore...

Comment: @lulu So 4 artists will work 4/6 as fast? That means to paint 8 walls we multiply 8 by 4/6 in the form $$v=\frac{s}{t} \Rightarrow s=vt$$?

Comment: Don't think in terms of formulas.  That's obviously tripping you up.  But, yes.  If $6$ artists take $4$ hours to get it done, $4$ artists will that $\frac 32\times 4=6$ hours.  But try doing it @MarkBennet 's way.  As he remarks, that's a nice approach that breaks things down to their core elements.

Answer (score 2):

$6$ graffiti artists painting $4$ walls in $2$ hours means one artist is responsible for $\frac{4}{6}$ walls in the $2$ hours. I assume same speed of all artists and equal split of work.

In $1$ hour, an artist does half of that, i.e., $\frac{\frac{4}{6}}{2}=\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$ walls/h. Here I assume an artist performs equally over time.

From this, if you have $4$ artists, they paint $4\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{3}$ walls/h. With this "*speed*", $8$ walls are painted in $\frac{8}{\frac{4}{3}}=6$ h.

Answer (score 0):

6 graffiti artists paint 4 walls in 2 hours. As an equation we could write this quite simply as $6g = 4w/2h$. Now we are asked to find the speed (walls per hour) of 4 graffiti artists, hence multiplying both sides by $4/6$ gives us the statement $4g = 16w/12h$. From this it is easy to find how long it takes for 8 walls to be painted by these 4 graffiti artists, for by simplifying the ratio we'll find $4g = 8w/6h$. 4 graffiti artists require 6 hours to paint 8 walls